# Functional equation: $f(3x) = 3f(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find $f(x)$ if: $$f: R \to R$$ $$f(3x) = 3f(x)$$

I've tried to find $f(x)$ by differentiating:

\begin{align}(f(3x))' &= (3f(x))'\\
3f '(3x) &=3f '(x)\\
f '(3x) &= f '(x)\\
f'(3x) - f '(x) &= 0\\
(f(3x) - f(x))' &= 0\tag{$\dagger$}\\
(2f(x))' &= 0\\
&\Downarrow\\
f(x) &= c\end{align}

for $c$ constant.

I know, that I am wrong, but I don't know why. I think, that my mistake is in $(\dagger)$. But I can't explain why.

Could you please help me to solve this equation and explain, what's wrong?

Comment: Step $4)$ and $5)$ are not equivalent. If you distribute the derivative in the paranthesis at step $5)$ you will not get $4)$.

Comment: For one thing, the function may not be differentiable. For another, $f(x) = x$ fulfills the criteria, so you can just check at which point that's no longer the case, and that's probably where you did the mistake.

Comment: Your step 1 assumes $f$ is differentiable.  In fact there are discontinuous non-differentiable solutions.

Comment: 4-6 are definitely wrong.

Comment: Try $$f(x)=ax$$ for your equation.

Comment: What are your assumptions on $f$?  This matters.

Comment: One hint for another method.  If you change variables $x=3^y$, that is $x=\exp(y\ln 3)$, then your new equation connects $y$ and $y+1$, which is a more common type of recurrence.

Comment: I've edited the question with MathJax - [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the user guide

Comment: Simply, the line that you correctly indicated as false assumes that $(f(3x))' = f'(3x)$, which is not correct

Answer (score 1):

In the second step 
$$f'(3x)=\frac{d(f(3x))}{d(3x)}$$
which can't be reconciled with what you've done in $(4)\to(5)$.
Indeed,
$$\frac{d(f(3x))}{dx}=\frac{d(f(3x))}{d(3x)}\frac{d(3x)}{dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your error: the line that you correctly indicated as false assumes that $(f(3x))′=f′(3x)$, which is not correct.

Now, to get a simple demonstration, I assume that $f'$ exists and is continue.

You have already shown that $f'(3x) = f'(x)$. Then,

$$f'(x) = f'(x/3) = f'(x/9) = \dots = f'(x/3^n)$$
By continuity ($n\to \infty$), $f'(x) = f'(0) := a$ and then $f(x) = ax$

Comment: I would like to understand why this answer was downvoted ... Maybe the fact that I assume that $f'$ exists and is continue. It is implicit from OP question

Answer (score 1):

Since no-one else has posted non differentiable solutions, I will give one here:

Let $f(x) = x$ for rational $x$ and let $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$.  This $f$ satisfies the functional equation.

More generally, define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb R$ by $x\sim 3x$.  For each distinct coset $C$ pick a constant $a_C$, and let $f(x)=a_C x$ for $x\in C$.